# How to find out do I have MLC or SLC SSD? (model: TOSHIBA THNSFC128GBSJ)

Tags: ssd

Please help to find out is **TOSHIBA THNSFC128GBSJ** SSD 
MLC or SLC SSD?

Comment: Google didn't help...I tried, really :D

Comment: Have you opened it up and had a look?

Comment: @Joe I thought about it. I have to disassemble my notebook. Actually I just want to know if it's possible to know it's programmaticaly. And I think that's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Toshiba that drive is a member of their HG3 family ("HG Series Solid State Drives")

See: http://www.toshiba-components.com/ssd/lineup/hg.html

Although they don't seem to specify SLC vs. MLC there, additional reference to the HG3 SSDs can be found [here at ssd.toshiba.com](http://ssd.toshiba.com/MLC-SSD-overview.html), which states:

> Toshiba's new HG3 **MLC** SSD drives provide a high level of performance with a maximum sequential read speed of 220MB per second (MBps) and maximum sequential write speed of 180MBps.

So short of a call to Toshiba to confirm, I'd have to go with it being an MLC.

Comment: Nope, those are different! Mine is exactly: THNSFC128GBSJ while on the link those are THNSNC series. Strange! But thanks for the link. Something is better than nothing.

Comment: True enough, but the THN drives are their consumer-grade drives, which all use MLC (cheaper, and easily brought into the 100GB+ sizes).  Their enterprise drives use SLC (eSLC even); those product codes start with MK (ie: MK1001GRZB).  The mild difference in the part number (SFC instead of SNC) is probably due to the channel the drive came from (ie: OEM vs. retail), and/or the country of intended sale, etc.